# Linking a PHP script to an HTML document

Tags: php, html

I would like to run a php script which is the forr action in an html document. The HTML code i have is as follows

```
<html><head><title>Using PHP</title></head>
<body>
<form action="form.php" method="post">
IP ADDRESS:<input type="text" name="IP"><input type="submit"><form>
</body></html>
```

I am using Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS so i have saved this file to /var/www . The php script that i have titled form.php, which is also in /var/www is as follows

```
<?php
echo "Todd"
?>
```

When i paste `http://10.0.0.98` into my browser, i get the form and when i click on submit, it downloads something which cannot be opened. I would want to view the script results on the browser. I do not know where i am going wrong, still very much new to PHP.

Comment: Have you tried: `localhost/your_html_form`  or `localhost/form.php`. in your browser. What does it give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is better suited to another StackExchange forum like [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), since it is about general Web programming that is not specific to Ubuntu per se.

That said, I see one flaw in your html in that you don't have a proper closing `</form>` tag. It would also be standard practice to have the form encoding included in the `<form>` tag as well, such as `enctype="multipart/form-data"` And since your PHP page is not really reading any of the input of the form, the PHP page should function if you simply enter `http://10.0.0.98/form.php` in your browser.